# New Teams update removes setting to disable new calls appearing in a pop-up window?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Dear developers of Microsoft Teams,

Today when joining a Teams meeting I noticed that I got a pop-up window for the meeting I was about to join. I immediately thought this was pretty weird, as I disabled the setting regarding that functionality.

This specific setting gave the user the option to have meetings be created in a seperate pop-up window, or to keep it in the same original application window.

For me this worked perfectly, als I much preferred to keep everything in one place. However, when searching for this setting in the settings tab, I noticed that the setting is now gone, thus forcing users to work with a pop-up window.

I have no idea why this setting was removed, but I would really love to get it back ASAP. I personally believe it's better to let the users themselves decide how they prefer to use Teams.

As this isn't a new feature that's being requested, but rather asking for a feature to come back from a previous version, I hope that it can be implemented back into Teams soon!

I hope to hear from the team about why the decision to remove the option was made, and if the setting can be brought back!

Kind regards,
Joshua

Comment: This is not really a stack overflow question.  You should (I believe) head over to the Teams UserVoice site to state your question/request.  https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programing question but a query to Microsoft to change there product.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please rise [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/) for this.